# Questions about using Matlab to plot reflection coefficient

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use matlab to make a plot to show the reflection coefficient versus load resistance with X-axis 10^x.
my code below:

```
x = 1:1000; %define x from 10^0 to 10^3
y = ((x-50)/(x+50)); % this is the reflection coefficient equation
semilogx (x,y); % make the x-axis to show 10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3
```

somehow I got the right Y-axis, and X-axis, but the trace is not showing.

I don't know what part I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you forgot the . and didn't create a vector. The / is single operator ./ divide is for every element.

```
x = 1:1000; %define x from 10^0 to 10^3
y = ((x-50)./(x+50)); % this is the reflection coefficient equation
semilogx(x,y); % make the x-axis to show 10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3
```

[image]